Set backup path by a constant won't work
I try to set the backup path by a central defined variable. But Emacs gives me the error. What is the right way to use a (defconst ...)

Setting a string is ok and works when saving the file.

(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . "/home/i4w/arc/emacs")))

OK

Setting a constant string throws an error while saving the file.

(defconst const-arc-emacs-path "/home/i4w/arc/emacs")
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . const-arc-emacs-path)))

Wrong type argument: stringp, const-arc-emacs-path


Comma variant

(defconst const-arc-emacs-path "/home/i4w/arc/emacs")
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . ,const-arc-emacs-path)))

Wrong type argument: stringp, (\, const-arc-emacs-path)


(list (list ...)) variant

(defconst const-arc-emacs-path "/home/i4w/arc/emacs")
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (list "" const-arc-emacs-path)))

Wrong type argument: stringp, (const-arc-emacs-path)


(list (cons ...)) variant works

(defconst const-arc-emacs-path "/home/i4w/arc/emacs")
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons "" const-arc-emacs-path)))

OK

This question is similar to: How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The answer does not me helps me here. It is a simple adoption of the Emacs config.  The code with the string elements is the boiler plate stuff provided to set the backup-directory-alist and is quoted in that way.  I even don't know why it is quoted here. I could not understand, that a substitution of a common default value common would be so complicated. So use commas, backticks to put a simple value here?

Yes. You’re building a data structure, and the ' quotes it so that it is not evaluated. You could write '(("" . ,const-arc-emacs-path)), or you could write (list (list "" const-arc-emacs-path))

OK (list (cons "" const-arc-emacs-path)) seems to work.

The comma works only in list quoted with ` not with '  see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html

There is a typo in @db48x's comment: the single quote ' should be a backquote as @matteol points out. But with that change, everything works as in the linked question, which makes your question a duplicate. Please close it as such.

Yea, and I also forgot that an alist needs a list of conses :)

You quoted the variable name. Therefore the variable name is included in the value assigned to the variable, not the value of the variable it names. Search for other questions about quoting and unquoting to find many, many other similar questions all with answers.
